# How to make a col trigger object universal so I do not need to use multiple transforms?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a bunch of the same objects that the player can interact with and then instantly bounce away from. So you can go from object to object and continuously bounce in different directions.

Currently I use **public Transform bouncyCube** and then drag a "bouncy cube" object into the transform via inspector. But since I am using many of the same objects and also a trigger with Collider col, is there a way to use col to universally include all of those objects so that I do not need multiple transforms or scripts?

For example I have 5 bouncy cube objects, and for all 5 of those bouncy objects to function with this trigger, I need to add additional transforms and drag them all into the inspector. I just want one script and one transform (if possible) to include every single potential bouncy cube I might have.

```
public Transform bouncyCube;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "BouncyCube")
    {
        willBounce = true;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    if (willBounce == true)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(bounceHeight * -2f * gravity);
            canLeap = true;
        }
    }   

    if (canLeap == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(LeapForward());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to have a single instance of your script that is triggered by "bouncy cube" in the scene. To achieve this, you can add multiple colliders to the same `GameObject`. So, in your GameObject that has the script you shared, you'd add one collider for each bouncy cube and place it correctly. Then, `OnTriggerEnter` will be activated by each of those colliders. Note that this will only work if the bouncy cubes don't move, because the colliders aren't actually attached to the `Transform`s. I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you saying that if I have for example 15 "bouncy cube" objects, I would have to add 15 colliders to the same object? Is there any alternative to this if that's the case? I just tested something, I duplicated a bouncy object and when I enter its trigger, the bounce movement occurs on the original object because the original object is the one in my inspector.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes, you'd need to add all the colliders. However, there might be a way around it, depending on your setup. Could you edit your question to include a screenshot of your scene hierarchy, as well as the inspector for the object that has that script attached?